# Keep html at position fixed with a background image

Tags: html, css

I have a hit a problem where my background-image does not render on mobile devices (tested on IOS).

The problem seems to be due to the fact I use

```
html{
    position: fixed;
}
```

in my project, and this is needed, so I don't want to remove it.

The background image renders just fine on my desktop computer, it's just not working on my iDevices (haven't checked android).

I made a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/q19srbba/2/) test, you will notice the background image won't render on IOS Safari.

Is there any possible work arounds to get the background-image to render without removing `html{ position: fixed; }` ?

JsFiddle Code:

```
body{
  background: url('http://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/1487701021/eiffel-tower-paris-france-EIFFEL0217.jpg?itok=m0MZOYjh');
}

html{
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Don't know about IOS, but it works fine in Windows Phone.

Comment: What does the `position: fixed;` supposed to do for you ? i mean the HTML is already fixed

Comment: Why did you do an edit where you removed almost your entire post?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your `html` element is collapsing. Add width / height 100% to your `html` element:

```css
body{
  background: url('http://cdn-image.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1000/public/1487701021/eiffel-tower-paris-france-EIFFEL0217.jpg?itok=m0MZOYjh');
}

html{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```